# tools.jar exists, but cant find sun.security.tools.JarSignerResources

Tags: java, exception

I am seeing the following exception (on a Linux Java6-sun install, but not on OSX)

```
Caused by: java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name sun.security.tools.JarSignerResources, locale en_US
 at java.util.ResourceBundle.throwMissingResourceException(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(Unknown Source)
 at com.wuntee.aat.security.tools.JarSigner.<clinit>(JarSigner.java:96)
 ... 12 more
```

but, I can see that the tools.jar exists in the java install directory, and that tools.jar contains the JarSignerResource class. Any ideas?

Comment: Is the tools.jar in the classpath? I guess it's not.

Comment: its part of the base java install... /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/lib/tools.jar

Comment: It's part of the *JDK* install (because it's used by javac and other development tools), but it does not mean that it's is the classpath of every Java application. BTW, it's not in the base *JRE* install.

Comment: running the jar via 'java -classpath .:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/lib/tools.jar -jar myjar.jar' causes the same problem...

Comment: You can't use -jar and -classpath at the same time. Use 'java -classpath .:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/lib/tools.jar:myjar.jar com.wuntee.aat.security.tools.JarSigner (assuming JarSigner is the main class of your application)

Comment: the issue is tools.jar is somewhat os dependent, and i do not want to include it in the project (ie: osx does not even have a tools.jar). shouldnt java look in its $JAVA_HOME/lib directory for jars to include?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not related with not finding the jar. The problem is related with not finding some resource for en_US locale within the jar instead. 
Two things can be happening:

1. if you open the tools.jar file and check the content of sun\security\tools you will find that one of them doesn't have the resource JarSignerResources_en_US.class, or
2. check the default locate of the two different OS you are using: one of them should be en_US and the other is not. This is most probable.